# JMeter Command Line Execution - Returning Status

Tags: jmeter

I'm running jmeter test plans via command line and functionally its all working ok, but I want to return from jmeter two values: a boolean field indicating if an error was thrown by any step in the excecution (essentially a pass/fail indicator), and a value generated in jMeter and stored in a user defined variable. Is it possible to do this and if so how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I extended a BeanShell Listener script I had to write status of any errors to a txt file, as well as the variable I needed. Then I was able to parse this txt file in my batch file to extract the variable and check for pass/fail based on the existence of "error" in the file. I deleted the txt file after each execution to allow a new one to be genereated per execution.

Answer (score 1):

You could look at how the jmeter maven plugin extracts data for use in maven reports.

https://github.com/Ronnie76er/jmeter-maven-plugin/wiki

Answer (score 1):

You can add a [Beanshell Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Sampler) as a part of your test (last step). In this test step you can then write these values to a file. After the test is done you would have those values stored in a file.

Let me know if you need further explanation/example

Comment: In the case of an error being thrown the plan moves onto next Thread, assuming this Sampler would not get executed in this case?

Comment: this really depends on your test case structure. You could put this beanshell sampler in each of your tests, if you wouldn't see outcome from that particular group that would mean that you have error in your thread group.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the console exit code to match the test results of your JMeter tests follow this steps.

You need to have the `Generate Summary Results listener` in your JMeter test. This listener allwos to check for errors by analyzingh the console output. I found this approach [here](http://jmeter.512774.n5.nabble.com/Exit-code-as-indicator-of-functional-test-outcome-td5716077.html).

You basically analyze the Summery Results if any error occurred and set the console exit code accordingly.

**grep Approach**

Directly with the jmeter call using `grep`, described [here](http://jmeter.512774.n5.nabble.com/Exit-code-as-indicator-of-functional-test-outcome-td5716077.html)

```
#!/bin/bash
if java -jar ./apache-jmeter-2.9/bin/ApacheJMeter.jar -n -t x.jmx | grep "0
(0.00%)$"
then
  echo Success
  exit 0
else
  echo Failure
  exit 1
fi
```

**Python Approach**

or using Python

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
jmeter -n  -t script.jmx | process_results.py
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo '[TEST FAILED]'
else
    echo '[TEST SUCCESSFUL]'
fi
```

`process_results.py` - modified so it only alerts if error count > 0

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    print line,
    match = re.search('summary =[\s].*Err:[ ]{0,10}([1-9]\d{0,10})[ ].*',line)
    print 'Check in line if Err: > 0 -> if so Error occured -> Test fails: '
    print match
    if match :
        print "exit 1"
        sys.exit(1)
print "nothing found - exit 0"
sys.exit(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you run the jmeter with `-o reports/` option, you get the reports. Inside the targeted directory you can find a file named `statistics.json`. There you can find the total amount of errors of the run. I suggest you use `jq` cli as well.

For example.

```
    TOTAL_ERRORS=$(jq .Total.errorCount reports/statistics.json)
    if [[ "$TOTAL_ERRORS" -ne 0 ]]; then
      exit 1
    fi
```